# Outlook add-in: Adjoining Form Region not showing for Appointments in Inspectors

Tags: outlook, add-in, appointment

I am developing an Outlook add-in. I do it in C# code, not in XML.

I added an FormRegion to the project. The type of the FormRegion is adjoining. It is associated with message class 'IPM.Appointment'.

I specified that the FormRegion be displayed in Inspectors in read mode.

With the settings above, I am expecting the FormRegion appear in Inspector windows for appointments. However, when I open Outlook, switch to the 'Calendar' view, double-click an appointment, the popped up Inspector window does not have my FormRegion.

I tried the same steps for message class 'IPM.Notes' and it worked well -- when i double-clicked a mail in the 'inbox' folder, the popped up inspector showed my FormRegion at the lower part of the window.

Could someone help telling me the reason why my FormRegion is not working for appointments?

Thanks,

Richard